# Test the limit of read/write cycles of a USB flash drive

Tags: bash, usb-drive

I read from an wiki article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_flash#Write_endurance) 
that says flash storage has a limit of read/write cycles (for NAND flash this limit is about 10K-100K).

My question is: Is it possible to test/find out this limit on my PC in a relatively
short time (in a few hours or a few days)?

I wrote a simple script (/dev/sdb is flash disk), 
but since flash controller will do wear-levelling, 
I think this script may not work.

```
echo "0011223344556677" | xxd -r -p > a.bin

for ((n=0;n<1000000;n++)); do
     dd if=a.bin of=/dev/sdb
done
```

Comment: It may work over time, but if it's doing wear levelling, your best bet is to get the smallest drive you can find, and write to the whole thing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be easier to do something like this to fill the device with random data:

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/DEVICE bs=1M`

Over and over again until the device fails.

If you want to check for single bit errors you could do the following:

1. Fill the disk with zeroes - `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/DEVICE bs=1M`
2. Get the SHA-1 sum of the whole disk - `dd if=/dev/DEVICE | sha1sum`
3. Fill the disk with random data - `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/DEVICE bs=1M`
4. Repeat until the number from step 2 changes or the disk stops working

That should probably be wrapped up in a bash script to save you some time.

NOTE: I used /dev/DEVICE so nobody would accidentally copy and paste these snippets without thinking.  You'll need to change it to your specific device and be very careful that you get it right!

Comment: ++ for "I used /dev/DEVICE so nobody would accidentally copy and paste these snippets without thinking." Well stated! :-)

Comment: Thanks, it always scares me when I think that something I posted online could have just blown away someone's whole machine by accident.  :)